# Postman on Linux - Couldn't open sign-in link from app

Tags: linux, postman

I have just installed postman on Linux by following the guide [here](https://www.tecmint.com/install-postman-on-linux-desktop/). And I was able to open the postman desktop app. However, when I wanted to sign in by clicking the "Sign in" button on the upper right, the page below showed up and never directed me to any page to sign in (clicking "open it manually" didn't work either). The page just hung there until "Your request timed out" showed up.
[image]

I tried to open the app from terminal instead and I saw the following error:
[image]

I am not sure what's going on here but any insights would be much appreciated!

Comment: You have a good question, but you have posted to the wrong StackEachange site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). That said, I'm glad you were able to suss-out missing xdg-utils was the problem. You may want to consider moving the question and answer to the Unix & Linux site.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself. It's because `xdg-utils` was not installed on my linux. `yum install xdg-utils` fixed the issue.